# Directive doesn't update parents scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

all the code http://jsfiddle.net/mato75/o9e3cb56/

directive:

```
scope: { attrs: '=?' }
```

main ctrl:

```
this.val = { val: '1', title: '2' };

$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () { return this.val.title }), function () {
     doSomethingOnChange()
});
```

html:

```
<div dirc x-attrs="ctrl.val">
```

When I change title in directive, main controllers watch is not dispatched.

Comment: How do you change `attrs.title` inside directive?

Comment: The reason why it doesn't work is `how` you change `attrs.title`. if you want to get help, elaborate on that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example which does what I think you intend: http://plnkr.co/edit/pRih6ldttukJ9ZwrWNsF?p=preview

I am wondering why you are using this method of setting the $watch:

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () { this.val.title }), function () {
    doSomethingOnChange()
});
```

In my code I used the simpler format:

```
$scope.$watch('ctrl.val.title', function() {
    console.log('The watch was dispatched!');
});
```

Of course, in this case you are coupling your controller to the name you choose in your view. Perhaps that is what you wished to avoid? In any case, the demo works so I hope that helps.

**Update:** I actually just realised the *real* reason why your code didn't work. In the $watch function, you forgot the `return` statement:

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function () { return this.val.title }), function () {
    doSomethingOnChange()
});
```

That should work now.

Comment: I am sorry, forgot to write it, but it still doesnt work

Comment: But my demo *does* work, so just check it out carefully and see if you can figure out what is going wrong with yours.

Comment: If still no joy, we probably need to see more of your code, such as the directive itself, as @dfsq suggests above.